# Custom JSON response with Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

**Model**

```
public class Organisation {

    private String name;

    public Organisation() { }

    public Organisation(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**controller**

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Organisation> getAll() {
        Organisation organisation = new Organisation("google");
        List<Organisation> organisations = new ArrayList<>();
        organisations.add(organisation);
        return organisations;
    }
```

This will give out response like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "google"
  }
]
```

What if we want something like this:

```
{
  "data": [{
    "type": "organisations"
    "attributes": {
      "name": "google"
    }
  ]
}
```

So how to customize the json. I know that Spring MVC by default uses Jackson to convert models into JSON. Is there a way to customize it. I am trying to send response in JSONApi standard. Also can someone tell how to create links in responses

Answer (score 2):

Create Classes as:

```
public class Object1 {
   private List<Object2> data;

   public Object1() {
   }

   public Object1(List<Object2> data) {
      this.data = data;
   }
   //getters and setters
}

public class Object2 {

   private String type;
   private Object3 attributes;

   public Object2() {
   }

   public Object2(String type, Object3 attributes) {
      this.type = type;
      this.attributes = attributes;
   }
    //getters and setters
}

public class Object3 {
   private String name;

   public Object3(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public Object3() {
   }

    //getters and setters
}
```

Now your controller method shoul be like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object3 getAll() {
        List<Object2> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(new Object2("organisations", new Object3("google")));

        return new Object1(data);
    }
```